# Creating a dataframe from a dictionary is giving me a could not broadcast error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a data frame from a dictionary I have and it gives me an error that says:

```
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape
> (1)
```

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests.api import request
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import Tag, NavigableString
baseurl = "https://www.olx.com.eg/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
}

product_links = []
for x in range(1,13):
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.olx.com.eg/jobs/?page={x}", headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")


    product_list = soup.findAll("div", class_="ads__item")
  


        
    for item in product_list:
        for link in item.findAll("a",href=True):
            product_links.append(link['href'])


    for thing in product_links:
        if '#' in product_links: product_links.remove('#')


# test_link = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/ad/-IDcjqyP.html'

for link in product_links:
    r = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
    job_title = soup.find('h1',class_="brkword")
    job_location = soup.find('strong',class_="c2b")
    job_date = soup.find('span',class_="pdingleft10 brlefte5")
    try:

        seniority = soup.find_all('td',class_='value')[0].text.strip()
    except:
        print("")

    try:    
        full_or_part = soup.find_all('td',class_='value')[1].text.strip()
    except:
        print("")
    try:    
        education_level = soup.find_all('td',class_='value')[2].text.strip()
    except:
        print("")
    try:
        sector = soup.find_all('td',class_='value')[3].text.strip()
    except:
        print("")
    description = soup.find_all('p',class_='pding10')

    df = {
    "Job Title" : job_title,
    "Job Location" : job_location,
    "Post Date" : job_date,
    "Seniority Level" : seniority,
    "Full or Part time" : full_or_part,
    "Educational Level" : education_level,
    "Sector" : sector,
    "Job Description" : description
    }


job_data = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Please tell me how I can transform the data I have into a data frame so I can export it into a csv
first of all I was trying to to scrape this jobs website and it scraped it successfully returning 500 jobs in the dictionary but I was unfortunately not able to transform the code into a dataframe, so later on i can export that out to a csv file, so i can do some analysis on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create dataframe from the job ads, you can try next example (some column names needs to be renamed from arabic to english though):

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


baseurl = "https://www.olx.com.eg/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36"
}

product_links = []
for x in range(1, 2):  # <-- increase the range here
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.olx.com.eg/jobs/?page={x}", headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

    product_list = soup.findAll("div", class_="ads__item")

    for item in product_list:
        for link in item.findAll("a", href=True):
            if link["href"] != "#":
                product_links.append(link["href"])

all_data = []
for link in product_links:
    print(f"Getting {link} ...")

    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link, headers=headers).content, "lxml")

    d = {}

    job_title = soup.find("h1").get_text(strip=True)
    job_location = soup.find("strong", class_="c2b")
    job_date = soup.find("span", class_="pdingleft10 brlefte5")

    d["title"] = job_title
    d["location"] = job_location.get_text(strip=True) if job_location else "N/A"
    d["date"] = job_date.get_text(strip=True) if job_date else "N/A"

    for table in soup.select("table.item"):
        d[table.th.get_text(strip=True)] = table.td.get_text(strip=True)

    all_data.append(d)

job_data = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(job_data)
job_data.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help for the second time Andrej!  could not have done the project without you :')